# php mysql timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I need to track the date and time a user was created in my mysql database. I have column called 'created' and the data type as TIMESTAMP.

The problem is that when a user changes their password or other information the TIMESTAMP value changes. How can I set this to not change????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may simply want to set its default clause to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (as @[Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009611/php-mysql-timestamp/3009661#3009661) and @[dcp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009611/php-mysql-timestamp/3009640#3009640) noted in the other answers):

```
CREATE TABLE your_table (
   ...
   `created_timestamp` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Test case:

```
CREATE TABLE tb (`a` int, `c` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

INSERT INTO tb (a) VALUES (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

SELECT * FROM tb;
+------+---------------------+
| a    | c                   |
+------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2010-06-09 23:31:16 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

UPDATE tb SET a = 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

SELECT * FROM tb;
+------+---------------------+
| a    | c                   |
+------+---------------------+
|    5 | 2010-06-09 23:31:16 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

**EDIT:**

In my original answer I suggested using a `DATETIME` column with a `DEFAULT` clause set to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. However this is only possible when using the `TIMESTAMP` data type, as [stated in documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> The `DEFAULT` value clause in a data type specification indicates a default value for a column. With one exception, the default value must be a constant; it cannot be a function or an expression. This means, for example, that you cannot set the default for a date column to be the value of a function such as `NOW()` or `CURRENT_DATE`. The exception is that you can specify `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as the default for a `TIMESTAMP` column.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you don't have the timestamp column set up properly:

Check out the [guide](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html):

```
*

  Auto-initialization and auto-update:

  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

*

  Auto-initialization only:

  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

*

  Auto-update only:

  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0 ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

*

  Neither:

  ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT 0
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a datetime column. Timestamp auto-updates.

Answer (score 3):

Change it to `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` otherwise it will autoupdate. From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html):

> In a CREATE TABLE  statement, the first TIMESTAMP column can be declared in any of the following ways:
>
> With both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clauses, the column has the current timestamp for its default value, and is automatically updated.
>
> **With neither DEFAULT nor ON UPDATE clauses, it is the same as DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.**
>
> With a DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  clause and no ON UPDATE clause, the column has the current timestamp for its default value but is not automatically updated.

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

Making it a DateTime?

Answer (score 0):

- Leave the format as is but whe you insert formate the inserted string correctly with `date()`.
- Then need to be `updating` when the user changes their info.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the table, you should omit the ON UPDATE

```
ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

should be

```
ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

[link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Under attributes, disable "on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP".

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit dirty in your case, but you can temporary disable auto update by doing :

```
UPDATE woot SET password=<value_to_set>, timestamp_colum_name=timestamp_colum_name;
```

(Found it there : http://www.xarg.org/2010/06/disable-on-update-current-timestamp-in-mysql/)